# PostGIS Simplification on topogeometry does not respect topology?

Tags: postgis, topology

I'm testing the code in the book "PostGIS in Action" (2nd ed) on Topology-based Simplification:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _temp_table; CREATE TABLE _temp_table AS
SELECT feat_name, ST_Simplify(topo,150) As topo_simp
FROM ch13.neighbourhoods;
```

This is supposed to produce a simplified polygon layer that respects topology. However, I am getting a simplified layer that breaks topology. In fact, the result is identical to the simplification after converting the `topo` field to `geometry` type:

```
...
SELECT feat_name, ST_Simplify(topo::geometry,150) As geom_simp
FROM ch13.neighbourhoods;
```

I double checked that the topo field is of the topogeometry type:

```
=> SELECT feat_name, topo FROM ch13.neighbourhoods LIMIT 1;

 feat_name |   topo    
-----------+-----------
 James Bay | (2,1,1,3)
(1 row)
```

*Am I missing something here, or does anyone else have a similar experience?*

I am using PostGIS 2.5.1 under Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Not sure about the answer to your question but as an alternative you may want to check GRASS GIS's v.generalize (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.generalize.html) which keeps topology intact.